# How to replace part of email address with another string in pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with email addresses. I need to replace every ending of email address with a '.mn'. What I mean by ending is '.org', '.com', etc.

**`Ex. John@smith.com becomes John@smith.mn`**

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is what I have so far, but this is not replacing or giving me an error message:

```
email['ADDR'] = email['ADDR'].str.replace(r'[.]{2,}', '.mn')
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
email['ADDR'] = email['ADDR'].str.replace('.{3}$', 'mn')
```

---

If you need to handle variable length domains (`.edu`, `.com1`, and so on), you can use:

```
email

             ADDR
0  john@smith.com
1    test@abc.edu
2    foo@bar.abcd

email['ADDR'].str.replace('\..{2,}$', '.mn')

0    john@smith.mn
1      test@abc.mn
2       foo@bar.mn
Name: ADDR, dtype: object
```

Comment: Just open the question and there is your nice and succinct answer ~

Answer (score 2):

Another method which will handle variable length top-level endings is to use [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html#pandas.Series.str.rsplit):

```
In[72]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['John@smith.com','John@smith.x','John@smith.hello']})
df

Out[72]: 
              email
0    John@smith.com
1      John@smith.x
2  John@smith.hello

In[73]:
df['email'] = df['email'].str.rsplit('.').str[0] +'.mn'
df

Out[73]: 
           email
0  John@smith.mn
1  John@smith.mn
2  John@smith.mn
```

This will find the last trailing dot, takes the left hand side and append the new desired suffix

Comment: Ah, nice and simple.